# jQuery disabling login submit button if username field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to disable the submit button if the username textbox field is empty.

```
$("#txtUserName").bind("input propertychange change keyup  paste", setButtonState);
var setButtonState = function () {
    if ($("#txtUserName").val().trim() == "") {
        $("#login").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#login").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine in all scenarios except that,when the user selects username which is saved earlier(autocomplete).
I cannot set the autocomplete off option for the textbox.

How can I catch the event when user selects text in autocomplete usernames?

Comment: `i cannot set the autocomplete off option for the textbox.` Do you mean you don't know how to, or are not allowed to?

Comment: Wouldn't `<input name="username" required>` be easier than messing around with all that JS?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is "select". You can bind it to your input field.

Comment: I tried with select event,but it is not working on IE browser.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan am not allowed to off autocomplete.

Comment: @Quentin I want to disbale the button instead of having required field

Comment: Are you talking about the browsers inbuilt autocomplete or jquery ui autocomplete widget..? Can you provide a demo where it doesn't work..? Because if it is jquery ui autocomplete, as far as I know, user has to type something to trigger autocomplete suggestions. Typing will trigger native `input` event and your code should work.

Comment: browsers inbuilt autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind your input field to the additional event `select`, which is fired when a user selects something from his autocompletion.

This would be your code then. I just added `select` and rearranged your code a little bit. Also I run `setButtonState()` once at the domready to be sure it's disabled.

```
var setButtonState = function () {
    if ($("#txtUserName").val().trim() == "") {
        $("#login").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#login").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
$("#txtUserName").bind("input propertychange change keyup paste select", setButtonState);
setButtonState();
```

I have also updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lurw1b7/6/) to demonstrate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have tried this it works on mozilla browser but on IE.I am using IE10 version.Please suggest.

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI binding on "input" should fire every time the input field is changed. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI I updated fiddle and answer. Check if it works now.

Comment: I tried this,it is working on Mozilla,not on IE.I want it to work on IE as well.

Comment: for me it's working in ie9+. is my fiddle not working for you?

Comment: I tried it and it is not working.I am using IE10 version.It is working only if the txtusername textbox loses focus

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI what os are you using? check if you maybe have compatibility mode in intranet enabled or something like that.

Comment: I ma using Win7 Os.I don't see any compatibility modes enabled.Even i tried at my home and still facing issue with IE10.